# ng serve/build not working after angular upgrading from 11 to Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular11, angular-upgrade, angular13

Tried to upgrade the angular from 11 to 13, here is my `package.json`. As I was using angular 11 which was having a slow build then I decided to upgrade it to 13 now it doesn't build or serve.

```
{
  "name": "metronic-angular-demo1",
  "version": "7.1.6x",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "rtl": "webpack --config webpack-rtl.config.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.2.5-2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
    "highlight.js": "^9.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-editor": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "3.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.10",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

now if I try to use `ng serve` then it shows like this.
[image: no output]

no output is shown if I use it, using any build or serve shows no result at all.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I'm also facing the same unable to get where's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue while upgrading to angular 13. I resolved it by upgrading my angular-cli, you can directly upgrade your angular-cli version globally by using update command of ng. so you can do it by below command

> ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Now you can check the updated version using below cmd.

> ng version

If the above method does not work another way is by using uninstalling and reinstalling angular cli.
Follow below steps in order to completely uninstall old angular-cli and resinstall angular 13.

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

> npm cache clean --force

> npm cache verify

> npm install -g @angular/cli

again to verify version, use "ng version".

Comment: worked like this way `ng update @angular/cli@12--allow-dirty --force` --> `ng update @angular/cli@latest--allow-dirty --force`